# problem with the join query

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT *
FROM 
        productinfo as p ,
        category as c
WHERE
        c.id IN (p.category) AND 
        p.pid='T3'
```

WHERE p.category will return (1,2,3,4,5)  from product info table which the id of the category.

Now i need category name used for T3 [product Id] ,but i am getting only the first category name.

Answer (score 0):

Your base query is the following

```
SELECT * FROM productinfo as p WHERE p.pid = 'T3';
```

Now you need to pull in categories, per product. This is a many to one relationship, so you need a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT * FROM productinfo as p 
LEFT JOIN category as c ON c.id = p.category
WHERE p.id = 'T3'
```

You need to learn the different types of joins and how they are used. Whenever I see someone use 'FROM table1, table2' 90% of the times it means they don't understand joins and they need a LEFT JOIN instead.

**Edit based on your comment**

Your datamodel is flawed. Since a product can contain multiple categories, this is really a many-to-many relationship. You should create a product_category table that connects product id's with category id's.

Comment: p.category contain category table's id in this format 1,2,3,4